# Error al editar archivo en Powershell con TOUCH

Tags: powershell

Al intentar editar archivo mediante TOUCH al igual que en linux, da error.

Crear archivo:

```
ni prueba.bat
```

Editar archivo:

```
touch prueba.bat
```

**Error: El término TOUCH no se reconoce como cmdlet...**

¿Hay alguna manera de editar el archivo en el propio powershell como en Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No existe el comando touch en **Powershell**, tampoco puedes usar un editor VIM o nano al igual que en Linux.

Lo que puedes usar es algo como esto:

```
start notepad archivoAEditar.txt
```

Si tienes un editor como **Visual Studio Code** puedes abrirlo así:

```
code archivoAEditar.txt
```

**Directamente en la terminal no podrás editarlo.**

Puedes echar un vistazo aquí para ver una alternativa:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cfa65a6f-3f8c-42ca-9978-bdbffdc99ec5/how-do-i-edit-a-text-file-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell